# How to import custom module the same way as pip-installed modules?

Tags: python, import, module

I feel really dumb asking this question, but it's a quirk of python I've put up with for awhile now that I finally want to fix.

On CentOS 7, given that I have "roflmao.py" and "__init__.py" in the directory:

```
 /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/roflmao
```

Why is it that when I'm using the python interpreter (and not in the directory containing roflmao.py), I must type:

```
from roflmao import roflmao
```

Instead of simply:

```
import roflmao
```

To gain access to "roflmao.py"'s functions and variables?  I can import re, collections, requests, or any PIP-installed module just fine, but not my own custom one.

How can I set things up to accomplish this?

Comment: Have you take a look to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4116384/3077939) ?

Comment: Thanks Aluriak!  That answer is basically what I need and I feel that DuckPuncher's is more specific and less buried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put `from roflmao import *` into `__init__.py`.

If you do this, then you don't really need to use `roflmao.py`.  Because it would then be pointless to do `from roflmao import roflmao`.  So it's best to just put the code from `roflmao.py` into `__init__.py`.

Comment: I've been watching your edits - you're totally right.  I ended up putting "from roflmao import *" in "\__init\__.py", and that totally worked!

Comment: Haha, sorry about that.

Comment: If you change your answer to "from roflmao import *" I'll set it as accepted.  The way you've suggested currently still necessitates the "from" thing I was trying to avoid.